# Валидация эмэйлов в кириллическом домене: регулярка не работает, как исправить?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Использую такое выражение:

```
/[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9._-]+@[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,4}/
```

почему-то не пропускает эмэйлы в русскоязычных доменах. Тестовый пример полностью:

```
<?php

$email = "mail@сайт.рф";

if (!preg_match("/[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9._-]+@[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,4}/", $email)) {
    echo "ERROR";
} else {
echo "Ok";
}
?>
```

Comment: добавьте в шаблон модификатор `u`

Comment: и модификатор `i`, тогда  большие буквы из выражения смело убирайте

Comment: `/[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9._-]+@[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,4}/u`